# How do dynamically fill 2nd listbox based on 1st listbox on initial load of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listbox

If I have a couple listboxes where the first listbox is populated via a json file and then the second is populated based on what is selected in the first, how do you get the 2nd to populate onload?

First listbox loads grabbing for example myfile.json, which has

```
    { [ { "snow project", "12345" }, { "rain project", "23245" } ]}
```

To generate a listbox with for example snow project as key and val is 12345.  The second listbox grabs myfile_12345.json to populate the second box.  If I select rain project it does grab data and fill the second listbox fine, but I want the 2nd listbox to have data onload for whatever the first selected item is, which may change as content in myfile.json file changes.

Comment: p.s. there will be a 3rd listbox, yes, filled based on 2nd listbox next.

Answer (score 0):

The same code to create the listbox allowed me to set the 2nd.  I am not sure how easy or practical this will be when I add more.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var $select = $('#project');
            $.getJSON('bamboo_projects.json', function(data,status) {
                    $select.html('');
                    $.each(data, function(key,val) {
                            if ( val.id != 'undefined' && $('#project option:selected').length == 0) {
                                    getRelease(val.id);
                            }
                            $select.append('<option value="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</options>');
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

I check during creation for 1st box for when it is about to add first option and run the same code I use to get the 2nd box content.

Note that I did try var selected_item = val.id, but selected_item goes out of scope after the $.each and $.getJSON code completes, so I use the value within the $.each loop instead.  Ideas on how to keep the value in scope?  I tried to set var selected_item outside of the $.getJSON/$.each loop, but it still did not keep the value.